# Opensuse Tumbleweed black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: x11, opensuse, kde-plasma, tumbleweed

My system is openSUSE Tumbleweed 20210408. After the update, I couldn't open KDE and also I can't see any login area just a black screen with a blinking cursor.

When I wrote

```
journalctl -b 0 -p 4
```

I saw output.

```
Apr 13 16:49:04 localhost gnome-session-binary[1364]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Apr 13 16:49:04 localhost /usr/libexec/gdm/gdm-wayland-session[1363]: dbus-daemon[1363]: [session uid=456 pid=1363] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.2' (uid=456 pid=1364 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr")
Apr 13 16:49:04 localhost /usr/libexec/gdm/gdm-wayland-session[1363]: dbus-daemon[1363]: [session uid=456 pid=1363] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Apr 13 16:49:04 localhost gdm[1283]: Gdm: gdm_session_handle_secret_info_query: assertion 'self->user_verifier_interface != NULL' failed
Apr 13 16:49:04 localhost gdm-autologin][1395]: gkr-pam: couldn't get the password from user: Conversation error
```

How can I solve this problem?